# Sqlite3 causing problems for bundle install and gem install

Tags: rubygems, sqlite, bundler, macports

Using Rails, whenever I try to do anything like "bundle install" or sudo gem install someGem, I get these same errors about sqlite3. I've tried both

```
sudo port install sqlite3 +universal
```

and

```
sudo port install rb-sqlite3 +universal
```

But neither has helped. Here is the error:

```
cmu-435163:photoGlass dpieri$ sudo gem install taps 
Password: 
Building native extensions.  
This could take a while... 
ERROR:  Error installing taps:  
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes 
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no 
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal' 
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the 
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed *** 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  
Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  
You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:     
--with-opt-dir  
--without-opt-dir   
--with-opt-include  
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    
--with-opt-lib 
....

....
Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection. Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

UPDATE:
I found the mkmf.log file and here are its contents:

```
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h...
-------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I.
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0
-I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/local/include -I/usr/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common    conftest.c -o conftest.i" checked program was: /* begin */ 1: #include <sqlite3.h> /* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in
-lsqlite3... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I.
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0
-I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/local/include -I/usr/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib
-L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/sw/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.       -lruby -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl  " conftest.c: In function ‘t’: conftest.c:3: error: ‘sqlite3_libversion_number’ undeclared (first use in this function) conftest.c:3: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once conftest.c:3: error: for each function it appears in.) checked program was: /* begin */ 1: /*top*/ 2: int main() { return 0; } 3: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_libversion_number; return 0; } /* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I.
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0
-I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/local/include -I/usr/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib
-L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/sw/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.       -lruby -lsqlite3  -lpthread -ldl  " ld: warning: directory '/sw/local/lib' following -L not found ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file Undefined symbols:   "_sqlite3_libversion_number", referenced from:
      _t in ccSWkK1V.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status checked program was: /* begin
*/ 1: /*top*/ 2: int main() { return 0; } 3: int t() { sqlite3_libversion_number(); return 0; } /* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Do you have the Xcode developer tools (incl. gcc) installed?

Comment: I installed the latest version of Xcode and the developer tools about 2 months ago. I've been installing gems just fine up until a few days ago

Comment: What does `which sqlite3` give you?

Comment: Which sqlite3 gives me: /opt/local/bin/sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

1. Did "which -a ruby" and "which -a
   sqlite3" and "which -a gem" to
   realize I had two or three versions
   of each
2. Use port to uninstall all the versions of Ruby, Sqlite3, and rubygems it had installed
3. Manually uninstall the other sqlite3 that was not along the same
   path as Ruby and Rubygems
4. Once Ruby, Rubygems, and Sqlite3 were all along the same bath
   (usr/bin) it all works fine again.

Comment: How did you manually uninstall sqlite3. It does not allow me to do that?