# Sqlite3 errors on migrate, nokogiri errors on bundle install, gem conflicts after migrating to Rails3 & doing some merging. (Mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, sqlite, nokogiri

Wow, Update, solved!!  I added a line into the gemfiles to tell it the range for my mac version of nokogiri, like it says here: [Make bundler use different gems for different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642085/make-bundler-use-different-gems-for-different-platforms), if you search for Stefan.  It appears crossing from windows to mac development was the culprit.

Learning how gems work on a mac with rails3, because I'm having sqlite3 / nokogiri / gem / bundler issues with Ruby & Rails3 (on my mac)...

The problems starting just after upgrading to Rails 3.0.4 and ruby 1.9.1.  Also, my teammate is coding in Windows and I'm on a Mac.  My friend just upgraded the project to Rails3, while on his Windows PC, and now I've cloned it onto my Mac with Git...and am getting these errors.

When I do "**rake db:migrate**" on our project, I get this error in red in shell:

*You have requested:
  sqlite3 >= 0

The bundle currently has **sqlite3 locked at 1.3.3**.
Try running `bundle update sqlite3`*

I don't know what that means or how to solve it.

Here's what's uncommented in my Gemfile:

gem 'rails', '3.0.4'

gem 'sqlite3'

It has many commented out, like:

(  # gem 'nokogiri'

(  # gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

My Gemfile.lock has these, among others:

```
nokogiri (1.4.4.1-x86-mingw32)

sqlite3 (1.3.3-x86-mingw32)
```

But troubles...

I thought I could solve this by doing "sudo port install sqlite3", which completed.  I also have done "bundle update sqlite3".  This seemed to complete, but then led me to another error:

***You have requested:
  nokogiri ~> 1.4.2

The bundle currently has nokogiri locked at 1.4.4.1.
Try running `bundle update nokogiri`***

When I do "bundle update nokogiri", it seems to fail and gives me the same error again.  This is the step that I can't get through.

Among many things in my **Gemfile.lock** i do have these:
    **nokogiri (1.4.4.1-x86-mingw32)
    sqlite3 (1.3.3-x86-mingw32)**

And those are what seem to be causing the error.  I tried changing to (~> 1.0.0.0) etc to see if a less specific number would work but nope.

I also tried this specific nokogiri installation:
sudo port install libxml2 libxslt
sudo gem install nokogiri

But even after this, I see this:
** Execute db:drop
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/Mike/Desktop/MikeFiles/betheduke2/BeTheDuke/**nokogiri**/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:126:in`rescue in block (2 levels) in '

Not sure what this means.

I also installed MacPorts in order to be able to install sqlite3, using "**sudo port install sqlite3**" http://www.macports.org/install.php
[Unable to install sqlite3-ruby gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520347/unable-to-install-sqlite3-ruby-gem)

This seemed to successfully go through an extensive sqlite3 installation, but now that this is all finished, and when I attempt rake db:migrate, I'm still getting the sequence of sqlite3 errors.  Then I do the bundle install, seemingly a success, then I'm getting the same old nokogiri error on repeat until I stop.

I also see this forum, https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/387.  This suggests it's a "bundler issue" or a "gem version inconsistency", but I'm not sure if that's the case, what I should do.  Edit the Gemfile?  Should I change that to the version that I have?

Strange thing is that in my "gem list", I have "sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)" but not nokogiri.  Then, when I close Terminal and re-open, and re-run "rake db:migrate", then it kicks off the sqlite3 error first, then when I run bundle install, then it goes back to the nokogiri error.

This stack post said maybe it's because there are too many versions of sqlite3 on my computer: [Sqlite3 causing problems for bundle install and gem install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732006/sqlite3-causing-problems-for-bundle-install-and-gem-install)

Here is what I have:
$ which -a sqlite3
/opt/local/bin/sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3

$ which -a gem
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/gem
/Users/Mike/.rvm/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem

$ which -a ruby
/Users/Mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
/Users/Mike/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Do you think these duplicates are conflicting with each other?  If so, what should I type to delete the right one?

Anyone know what to do?  Is it a "gotcha" in the upgrade to Rails3?  This has happened immediately after merging two git branches (one developed on the older Ruby/Rails2 combos, and the other developed in Ruby1.9.1/Rails3.0.4.)  We got a lot of merge errors even though none of the older versions of the two had been touched (we think it's a line ending issue cross mac & pc platforms), but not sure.  Maybe something about the merging & migration is impacting this gems?

Also, "How to install sqlite3" was helpful: [Problem installing sqlite3-ruby!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473214/problem-installing-sqlite3-ruby)

Comment: Great you solved the problem yourself, but consider making the solution clearer by answering your own question below...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually answering this, just making there be an answer by copy+pasting the OPs own answer that he edited into his question:

> Wow, Update, solved!! I added a line into the gemfiles to tell it the
>   range for my mac version of nokogiri, like it says here: Make bundler
>   use different gems for different platforms, if you search for Stefan.
>   It appears crossing from windows to mac development was the culprit.